# Querying a datetime range while taking into account the time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, datetime, timezone

I'm having a lot of trouble with a query. I don't really know how to explain this well, but I'm going to try.

Basically, we have several objects with a 'posted_at' field that keeps the date and time something was posted, with the time zone, in a datetime field. I need to query and get a range by date with those objects.

Previously, I was converting that to Date and comparing it to another Date object. The query was something like this:

```
Date(posted_at) >= :start_date AND Date(posted_at) <= :end_date
```

However, when Postgre converted it to Date, it lost the timezone info which caused innacurate results to the query.

So, I changed to this:

```
if start_date then
    start_time = Time.zone.parse("#{start_date.year}-#{start_date.month}-#{start_date.day}")
    conditions << "posted_at >= :start"
    hash[:start] = start_time
end

if end_date then
    end_time = Time.zone.parse("#{end_date.year}-#{end_date.month}-#{end_date.day}").end_of_day
    conditions << "posted_at <= :end"
    hash[:end] = end_time
end
```

While this gets me the accurate results, it also has horrible performance and is causing some timeouts in my application.

I couldn't find any other way to do this query and still keep the accurate results. Would anyone have some advice or ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to store timezone information in your database.

Here's a read that discusses some of the pitfalls:

http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

You'll get better results as tadman suggests: add a new field with your timestamp `at time zone 'utc'`, and index it. You'll then be able to grab stuff using `posted_at between ? and ?`.

Comment: Thanks Denis, that is really worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck converting your start and end times to UTC which would render the time-zone mostly irrelevant when making the query itself. This is done easily enough:

```
start_date.to_time.to_datetime.beginning_of_day.utc
end_date.to_time.to_datetime.end_of_day.utc
```

You can also adjust your query to be:

```
posted_at BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

Be sure to have an index on the fields you're searching, too, or you will get horrible performance.

Comment: The field was indexed and I've tried both methods. Still getting some timeouts, though :(

Comment: What query is it generating in `log/development.log`? Have you tried using `EXAMINE` on this query? It usually highlights where there may be problems.

Comment: I think the problem isn't really the query, but the fact that we have millions of rows... Since everything was working correctly when I was comparing dates, I talked to some people here and we'll create a new indexed column that keeps just the date, taking into account the time zone. Thank you for the help and info!

Comment: I've found it often works better if you create a `date` field rather than a `datetime` as the cardinality is lower, so that suggestion is certainly worth pursuing.